# Error Windows Worklfow Foundation 4.0 The input workflow type must be an Activity. Parameter name: workflowType

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation

I'm using windows workflow foundation 4.0 and I've created web Application on my button click event I have the following

```
Dictionary<string,object> dicobjParams=new Dictionary<string,object>();
            WorkflowRuntime workflowRuntime = Application["WorkflowRuntime"] as WorkflowRuntime;
            WorkflowInstance instance =workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(Activity1),dicobjParams);
            //workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(Activity1), dicobjParams).Start();
            workflowRuntime.WorkflowCompleted += new EventHandler<WorkflowCompletedEventArgs>(workflowRuntime_WorkflowCompleted);
            instance.Start();
```

but I always the following error

The input workflow type must be an Activity.
Parameter name: workflowType

as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909631/using-asp-net-with-windows-workflow-foundation) thread I've made sure that I'm using 4.0 application and workflow.

Please view [the code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10sGiMigVOdqYrEhhK0UDpz2PdRMWvOyG) sample of application for further understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using wwf 4.0 you cannot use WorkflowRuntime and instead of that you must use WorkflowApplication like :

```
Dictionary<string, object> dicobjParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Activity workflow1 = new MyApp.Activity1();
WorkflowApplication app = new WorkflowApplication(workflow1, dicobjParams );
app.Run();
```

i recommend to you to read : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx